# ViewPager's first two pages are disappearing, getItem() not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

### Context:

I'm making a music player and I'm currently working on the miniplayer. The miniplayer lives in a ViewPager along with a floating action button (FAB) for shuffle. Initially, only the FAB is seen on screen. When you click on the FAB, music playback starts, the Fab-Miniplayer ViewPager's page count goes from 1 to 2, and its page is set to the second page, where the miniplayer is. The miniplayer itself in the second page is a vertical viewpager, so one can swipe through to different songs. The miniplayer/vertical viewpager is backed by a PagerAdapter that gets songs from a `SongQueue` obejct.

### The Problem:

If I click on the FAB once, the miniplayer opens and everything works. Then I dismiss the miniplayer to stop playback by swiping back to the FAB page in the ViewPager. After clicking on the FAB to start playback and open the miniplayer for the second time, the first two fragments are never created. The miniplayer vertical ViewPager's PagerAdapter's getItem() methods are never called for item 0 and item 1. On a higher level, the first two songs in the miniplayer aren't showing up. Upon further investigation, the onCreate() methods are being called for the first two songs from the last time the miniplayer was opened, so I'm guessing the ViewPager is implementing some kind of caching or a reference is being held onto for too long because the miniplayer vertical viewpager thinks that it already has the first two songs the second time it is instantiated. Hopefully this problem description makes sense. If there are any questions, I'd be happy to try and go into more detail.

### The Code

#### SongsFragment

```
/**
 * Fragment used to display all of the songs on the device.
 */
public class SongsFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private static final String TAG = "SongsFragment";
    private SwipeListView mSwipeListView;
    private ViewPager fabMiniPlayerViewPager;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Initialize the loader to load the list of songs
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(SongCursorLoader.ALL_SONGS_ID, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_songs, parent, false);

        if (view != null) {
            mSwipeListView = (SwipeListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view_songs);
        }

        LinearLayout emptyView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_songs_empty, parent, false);

        mSwipeListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

        fabMiniPlayerViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_miniplayer_ViewPager);
        Integer viewPagerPageCount = new Integer(1);
        fabMiniPlayerViewPager.setTag(viewPagerPageCount);  // The fabMiniPlayerViewPager gets it's page count from the tag so it can be dynamically modified 
        fabMiniPlayerViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    // ShuffleFabFragment just houses a single button, the code is below
                    ShuffleFabFragment fragment = new ShuffleFabFragment();
                    fragment.setViewPager(fabMiniPlayerViewPager);
                    return fragment;
                }

                MiniPlayerFragment fragment = new MiniPlayerFragment();
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                Integer count = (Integer) fabMiniPlayerViewPager.getTag();
                return count.intValue();
            }
        });

        fabMiniPlayerViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                // Pass touch events to the list view behind it
                mSwipeListView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (!MusicPlayerService.isStopped()) {
            Integer viewPagerPageCount = 2;
            fabMiniPlayerViewPager.setTag(viewPagerPageCount);
            PagerAdapter adapter = fabMiniPlayerViewPager.getAdapter();
            fabMiniPlayerViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            fabMiniPlayerViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
        } else {
            Integer viewPagerPageCount = 1;
            fabMiniPlayerViewPager.setTag(viewPagerPageCount);
            fabMiniPlayerViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

#### ShuffleFabFragment

```
/**
 * Fragment representing the Shuffle Floating Action Button. On FAB click, it turns on shuffle and
 * plays a random song. Depending on the user preference, the mini-player will appear or the
 * Now Playing view will appear. The ShuffleFabFragment holds a reference to its containing
 * ViewPager so it can do the following:
 * <p/>
 * 1. Add the MiniPlayer fragment to the ViewPager to enable swiping & animations
 * 2. Remove the MiniPlayer fragment when it is swiped away
 * <p/>
 * Once the MiniPlayer is swiped away (to the right), it stops music playback.
 */
public class ShuffleFabFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "ShuffleFabFragment";
    private ViewPager fabMiniPlayerViewPager;

    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        fabMiniPlayerViewPager = viewPager;
        fabMiniPlayerViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                if (i == 0) { // MiniPlayer swiped away
                    Integer viewPagerPageCount = new Integer(1);
                    fabMiniPlayerViewPager.setTag(viewPagerPageCount);
                    PagerAdapter adapter = fabMiniPlayerViewPager.getAdapter();
                    Intent stopMusicIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicPlayerService.class);
                    stopMusicIntent.setAction(MusicPlayerService.ACTION_STOP);
                    getActivity().startService(stopMusicIntent);
                    fabMiniPlayerViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shuffle_fab, viewGroup, false);

        ImageView shuffleFabImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.shuffle_fab_ImageView);
        shuffleFabImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        // Scale up on touch to make the button appear to come closer
                        view.setScaleX(8f / 7f);
                        view.setScaleY(8f / 7f);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        view.setScaleX(1f);
                        view.setScaleY(1f);
                        break;
                    default:
                        view.setScaleX(1f);
                        view.setScaleY(1f);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        shuffleFabImageView.setClickable(true);
        shuffleFabImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String shuffleMode = PreferencesHelper.getShuffleMode(getActivity());

                if (shuffleMode.equals(PreferencesHelper.SHUFFLE_MODE_OFF)) {
                    PreferencesHelper.setShuffleMode(getActivity(), PreferencesHelper.SHUFFLE_MODE_SMART);
                }

                SongQueue.initializeQueue(null, true, Song.COLLECTION_TYPE_ALL_SONGS, getActivity().getApplicationContext(), null);
                Song firstSong = SongQueue.getSong(0);
                firstSong.play(getActivity(), false);

                // On Click, update the page count, then set page to miniplayer
                Integer viewPagerPageCount = new Integer(2);
                fabMiniPlayerViewPager.setTag(viewPagerPageCount);
                fabMiniPlayerViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                fabMiniPlayerViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

#### MiniPlayerFragment

```
/**
 * Hosts MiniplayerCardFragments and allows for song skipping
 */
public class MiniPlayerFragment extends Fragment implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    VerticalViewPager miniplayerCardViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_miniplayer, viewGroup, false);

        miniplayerCardViewPager = (VerticalViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.miniplayer_cards_ViewPager);
        miniplayerCardViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Song song = SongQueue.getSong(position);
                return MiniPlayerCardFragment.newInstance(song);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return SongQueue.getTotalSize();
            }
        });

        miniplayerCardViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

        SongQueue.addOnQueueChangeListener(new SongQueue.OnQueueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNextSongChanged() {
                onQueueChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onQueueChanged() {
                // Force re-layout to update fragments
                int queuePosition = SongQueue.getQueuePositionCurrentSong();
                PagerAdapter adapter = miniplayerCardViewPager.getAdapter();
                miniplayerCardViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                miniplayerCardViewPager.setCurrentItem(queuePosition, true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCurrentSongChanged() {
                onQueueChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        int queuePosition = SongQueue.getQueuePositionCurrentSong();

        if (queuePosition < position) {
            Intent nextIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicPlayerService.class);
            nextIntent.setAction(MusicPlayerService.ACTION_NEXT);
            getActivity().startService(nextIntent);
        } else if (queuePosition > position) {
            Intent prevIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicPlayerService.class);
            prevIntent.setAction(MusicPlayerService.ACTION_PREV);
            getActivity().startService(prevIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Force re-layout to update fragments
        int queuePosition = SongQueue.getQueuePositionCurrentSong();
        PagerAdapter adapter = miniplayerCardViewPager.getAdapter();
        miniplayerCardViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        miniplayerCardViewPager.setCurrentItem(queuePosition, true);
        SongQueue.setPagerAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

[Screenshots to help visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBMcO.jpg)

Comment: [Discussion on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2cljxz/question_viewpagers_first_two_pages_are/)

Comment: did you try to change the adapter to `FragmentPagerAdapter`?

Comment: A FragmentPagerAdapter would just keep the entire fragment in memory instead of just saving state. This is not a good solution as the root problem is that something is being held onto for too long. I tried using a FragmentPagerAdapter, but the root cause of the problem did not go away, although the problem manifested itself differently. Instead of showing up blank, the miniplayer (VerticalViewPager) showed up exactly how it looked like the first time it was initialized, instead of having the new fragments that it should have had.

Answer (score 1):

> After clicking on the FAB to start playback and open the miniplayer for the second time, the first two fragments are never created. The miniplayer vertical ViewPager's PagerAdapter's getItem() methods are never called for item 0 and item 1.

That is because the standard `ViewPager` already has pages 0 and 1. To clarify Sanket's answer, `setOffscreenPageLimit()` indicates how many pages to either side of the current page to create (via `getItem()`) and cache, and the minimum value is 1. Calls to `setOffscreenPageLimit(0)` will be ignored.

`getItem()` is *not* a means of finding out when the user switches pages. [A `PageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener%28android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener%29) is your means of finding out when the user switches pages.

> the miniplayer vertical viewpager thinks that it already has the first two songs the second time it is instantiated

It's not being instantiated a second time AFAICT.

Comment: How can I make those pages be instantiated a second time? The pages the VerticalViewPager has are going to be different so they need to be re-instantiated every time.

Comment: @AndrewOrobator: "The pages the VerticalViewPager has are going to be different so they need to be re-instantiated every time" -- no, they don't. Call a method on the fragment (or raise a method on an event bus) to tell it what model data to switch to, and have the fragment update its UI. "How can I make those pages be instantiated a second time?" -- you could try creating a fresh `PagerAdapter` and calling `setAdapter()` on the `ViewPager` again, though I'd just tell the existing pages what they now need to show.

Answer (score -1):

ViewPager has bydefault offScreenPagerLimit value 3.. so it may be not loading your first 2 item second time..

try with this

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

more [info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

Comment: It specifically says in the documentation that the default limit is 1, so that wouldn't do anything.

Comment: the default value is `1` and thats mean it will load `3` fragments, the current, previous and next.